# x or cross inside a textbox to clear the text box

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I want to put a cross button in my text boxes, for a wp7 app i am working on, something like this:
http://silverscratch.blogspot.com/2010/03/watermarked-textbox-part-i.html I dont like this solution.

I think there must be a better way. any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the other article by the same author [here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Create-a-Custom-Control-Inheriting-from-TextBox.aspx) [(archive)](http://web.archive.org/web/20110810201856/http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Create-a-Custom-Control-Inheriting-from-TextBox.aspx)

It is a custom control rather than a user control.