# How can I create a textbox with "X" on silverlight using XAML templates?

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, expression-blend

How can I create a textbox with "X" on silverlight using XAML templates? Which means the X should show on extreme right of the text box when it has some data.

When user clicks on X the text typed by user should clear out. I tried different styles but I was not able to create accurately.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [x or cross inside a textbox to clear the text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722032/x-or-cross-inside-a-textbox-to-clear-the-text-box)

Comment: You could use an [old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081106/clear-erase-textbox-content-with-button-click-event) of mine and just build it straight into the style template.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a composite control that consist of the textbox and an image. Bind to the image click event to clear the text content for that control.